# Restore database in SQL LocalDB using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, localdb, database-restore, sql-server-2012-localdb

I have a project developed in VB.NET and SQL Server 2012 LocalDB (v11) and I am need backup/restore facility in my application. Backup part is complete but I am stuck at restore part. This is the query I want to be worked (and its working fine in SQL Editor)

```
ALTER DATABASE [<.MDF File Path>] 
SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE

RESTORE DATABASE [<.MDF File Path] FROM DISK='<.bak File Path'
```

and here is the code in VB.NET I am trying to execute

```
Sub Restorequery(ByVal que As String)
    MainForm.Conn.Close()
    con = New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Database=Master;integrated security=True;")
    If Not con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then con.Open()
    cmd = New SqlCommand(que, con)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Sub
```

And here are the approaches I tried so far

1. Using the same query as above

   ```
   Restorequery("ALTER DATABASE [<.MDF File Path>] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE")
   Restorequery("restore database [<.MDF File Path>] from disk='<.bak File Path>'")
   ```

   and this results in an error

   > Exclusive access could not be obtained because the database is in use. RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
2. After finding reason for above issue (which is nonsense even after using `master` database while opening connection and closing all the previously opened connections using `MainForm.Conn.Close()` ), I tried second approach as per some links and references from Stackoverflow. And here are the queries I tried:

   ```
   Restorequery("use [master] ")
   Restorequery("alter database [<.MDF File Name>] set single_user with rollback immediate")
   Restorequery("restore database[<.MDF File Name>] from disk='<.bak File Name>'")
   Restorequery("alter database [<.MDF File Name>] set multi_user")
   Restorequery("use [<.MDF File Name>]")
   ```

   and here is the error I got while executing second query :

   > Additional information: User does not have permission to alter database <.MDF File Name with Path>, the database does not exist, or the database is not in a state that allows access checks. ALTER DATABASE statement failed.

Is there any other way to restore a SQL Server LocalDB using VB.NET ?

Comment: You should try to concatenate together both string commands (ALTER... RESTORE) separating them with a semicolon then execute on a single query using the same connection not two separated connections

Comment: Nope. Tried that but same problem as `Scenario 1`

Comment: Do you really need to set the database as SINGLE_USER on LocalDB? What happens if you execute directly the restore command (after closing every connection of your own app of course)

Comment: @Steve : Even after closing every connection, It gives me error like `Database is in use...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have Used this code in one of my project.

```
Try 
     With OpenFileDialog1
            .Filter = ("DB Backup File|*.bak;")
            .FilterIndex = 4
     End With

     OpenFileDialog1.FileName = ""

     If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
          Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
          SqlConnection.ClearAllPools()
          con = New SqlConnection(cs)
          con.Open()
          Dim cb As String = "USE Master ALTER DATABASE [" & System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath & "\BRH.mdf] SET Single_User WITH Rollback Immediate Restore database [" & System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath & "\BRH.mdf] FROM disk='" & OpenFileDialog1.FileName & "' WITH REPLACE ALTER DATABASE [" & System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath & "\BRH.mdf] SET Multi_User "
          cmd = New SqlCommand(cb)
          cmd.Connection = con
          cmd.ExecuteReader()
          con.Close()
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
```